# Grunt installed on Ubuntu but not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs, npm

I have installed Grunt by executing the below commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs

sudo apt-get install npm

npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Below is the terminal output after executing `npm install -g grunt-cli`

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)
```

Grunt should be installed globally but when I try `grunt --version` on the terminal it displays as below:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I have tried adding `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin` into ~/.bashrc but that does not help.

Even I have tried executing `grunt` command by going in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin` but no hope.

Please help me.

**EDIT:**
Here is the output of `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp javascript-common libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libssl-dev libssl-doc
  libv8-3.14-dev rlwrap zlib1g-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 261 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/684 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,116 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 172429 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nodejs (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
```

Here is the output of `ls -ln` from `/usr/local/bin`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 0 39 Jul  2 00:07 grunt -> ../lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 0 21 Jul  1 23:50 node -> /usr/local/bin/nodejs
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory` tells you everything. When you `apt-get install nodejs` I believe it puts `nodejs` but not `node` into your `/usr/local/bin`. So just symlink it like

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

and it should work.

**edit**: it would be

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

for your case.

Comment: *When you install nodejs I believe it puts nodejs but not node into your /usr/local/bin* — This depends on *how* you installed it. I believe the Debian/Ubuntu package does it that way. Installing it from the official sources calls it `node`.

Comment: Yep, clarified my post.

Comment: @Patosai Should I try chris-lead launchpad instead of Trusty http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2014/11/how-install-grunt-ubuntu-1404/

Comment: Or rather, your install log says it installed into `/usr/bin/nodejs` so just do the symlink from that.

Comment: You can use `which nodejs` to find the exact path.

Comment: I have removed nodejs and installed as you mentioned [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/) , then installed grunt-cli it worked, thanks @Patosai

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` solved the issue for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You've got to also install grunt to your project folder.  The grunt-cli package is just a stub that references the grunt package that lives in your project's `node_modules` folder.

`npm install grunt`